# Why ObjectIdGenerators.None cannot be resolved to a variable in Jackson 2?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee, jackson

I'm getting an error in eclipse with objectIdGenerators.None that
**ObjectIdGenerators.None cannot be resolved to a variable**.

Snippet

```
...
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.None, property = "@id") //Error
@Table(name = "t_user")
public class User implements Serializable {
...
```

Any idea about what can that be?

Comment: did you try ObjectIdGenerators.None.class?

Comment: Oh! That was the problem :( I forgot when I removed from ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class. Thanks a lot! I think I need a break!

Comment: @Joe-Welcome, a cup of coffee would surely help you .:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JsonIdentityInfo parameter generator need a class as a value.

**@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.None.class, property = "@id")**

```
...
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.None.class, property = "@id")
@Table(name = "t_user")
public class User implements Serializable {
...
```